# Remove tooltip if has no label

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I'm using this callback function to check if the hovered part of a chart has a label:

```
tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
      label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
        var label = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
        if(label !== 'undefined'){
          return label;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

But the tooltip arrow continues to appear. How can I remove it?

[image]

https://codepen.io/marcelo2605/pen/vWxyBL

Comment: An `undefined` variable will never be equal to the string `'undefined'`; I'd suggest simply removing the quotes that make it a string.

Comment: @DavidThomas Could you see my code at https://codepen.io/marcelo2605/pen/vWxyBL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `typeof` to check if label is undefined, so `hide()` or `destroy()` if need it.

```
tooltips: {
  callbacks: {
    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
      var label = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
        if(typeof label !== 'undefined') {
          return label;
        } else {
          label.destroy();
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

First use `typeof label != "undefined"` to see if its undefined or not.

Second use `optionsSistema.defaults.global.tooltips.enabled = false;` this will remove the label.

Here is a [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EbWNNB) of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
      label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
        var label = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
        if(label !== undefined){//use undefined instead 'undefined'
          return label;
        }else{
          return label.destroy()
         }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no other option than to use custom tooltip using custom property of tooltip object. Refer [custom tooltips](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#external-custom-tooltips)